# FB like button not actually liking the page

Tags: php, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

i have placed a FB Like button using iframe. When i click on it, it changes to Liked status. The count of people who like the page also increases. but when i log out and login in again, my like status is not retained. It shows me a "like" button again instead of the "already likes" one. when i check the page, my name does not appear in the "likes" list.

My code looks like below.

```
<iframe src='//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPagetoLike%2F&amp;width=30&amp;height=21&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;send=false&amp;appId=8705' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:70px; height:21px;' allowTransparency='true'></iframe>
```

is there anything that i need to manage via my code so that the button remembers? I looked up on Stackoverflow and found a mention to having fb:admins and fb:app_id but do not know where and how these are to be used with a Like button. Thanx in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was testing on the Localhost.... where obviously this option does not work. On testing this code with my hosted site it worked flawlessly.